# Why is the appearance of 2 identically created signature fields different in IText 7?

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, itext7

Creating 2 PdfSignatureFormFields the same way, i got 2 fields differently displayed in Adobe Reader : one with a little picture indicating a signature field and the other with no indication.

I use a Cell setNextRenderer call to create these fields as showed in the next extract :

```
    static private Cell createSignatureFieldCell(PdfDocument document,  String name, String label, PdfFont font) {
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    cell.setHeight(100);
    cell.setNextRenderer(new SignatureCellEvent(cell,name,label));
    return cell;
    }

    static private class SignatureCellEvent extends CellRenderer
    {
    protected String fieldname;
    protected String labelcontent;
    public SignatureCellEvent(Cell modelElement, String fieldname,String label) {
    super(modelElement);
    this.fieldname=fieldname;
    this.labelcontent=label;
    }

     @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) 
    {
    float x = getOccupiedAreaBBox().getLeft()  ;
    float y = (getOccupiedAreaBBox().getTop() +    getOccupiedAreaBBox().getBottom()) / 2;
    PdfDocument doc=drawContext.getDocument();
    PdfAcroForm form=PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(doc, true);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y - 10, 50, 50);
    PdfSignatureFormField field = PdfFormField.createSignature(doc,rect);
    field.setFieldName(fieldname);
    field.setRequired(true);
    form.addField(field);

   }
}
```

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: Here is ...https://1drv.ms/b/s!AkF6t4TavwMvchwL3wL2HXZKPuM

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience caused !

I've found the reason  of this behaviour:

It occurs when there is a field name collision in the document. 
In my case, a dynamically created field had the same name as a preexisting static field.

Regards,

David L.